# .htaccess file under sites/default/files/ stops css from loading

Tags: files, .htaccess

I'm working on a new installation of Drupal 10.2 and I noticed there's an .htaccess file in the files folder. This file is created automatically by Drupal. When I try to delete it, it gets created again.

The site looks like basic html with no CSS, but when I delete de file it goes back to normal until it gets created again and back to where I started.

I get 404 error in the browser developer tools for css and js files inside sites/default/files/css and sites/default/files/js

This is the content of the .htaccess file:

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything I need to change so this doesn't happen?

Comment: What does the web server access log indicate in these cases?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the logs, but it looks like it had to do with the settings to aggregate CSS and JSS files. As soon as I turn them off the site went back to normal

Answer (score -2):

I managed to find a solution unrelated to the .htaccess file.

I turned off 'Aggregate CSS files' and 'Aggregate JS files' under admin/config/development/performance.

As soon as I did that the site went back to normal.

Comment: Aggregation is a performance optimization. Disabling it in production is not recommended. You should continue studying the problem.